# No direct link to my form

Tags: cognito-forms

Where do I get a direct link to the form that I created (submit profile)?

It just shows the script for embedding, however, I would like to share direct web link for people to submit entries.

Answer (score 1):

I just reset the security flag on your account so you should see options to link to your form now. If you are still having problems please create a [bug report](https://www.cognitoforms.com/bugreport/) and we can research further.

Answer (score 0):

We are releasing an update today or tomorrow for [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) that will address this issue.  In the past we have limited direct links and are relaxing these restrictions moving forward.